# Javascript download doesn't work without seemingly unrelated return function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling a javascript problem that I think stems from a lack of conceptual understanding. I'll dive right in:

I have an web page that I want to have download a file when a button is clicked. The relevant html js is here:

```
// Js within html
var mypage = new MyPage();

$(document).ready(function() {
  mypage.onReady();
});
```

The document.ready executes on a button push which is definitely working. Next, my MyPage.js file:

```
onReady() {
  $('.my-form').on('submit', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/my/url',
      data: {
        'data': JSON.stringify(my_data)
      }
    }).done((response) => {
      window.location.href = response.msg;
    }).fail(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }); 
    return false; //relevant line
  });
}
```

Now that return false line looks irrelevant. However, for some reason when I take it out the download fails, and with it in it succeeds. Can someone explain to me why that is the case? Happy to post more info if it's needed.

Comment: It's in there because you're not submitting the form ...  Which is your initial function.  You're instead using ajax, so it's stopping the "submit" from happening ..

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.my-form').on('submit', function() {
```

Whether it is intentionally ot not, you are submitting a form or simply just the page, and by that the page is refreshed as soon the button is clicked.

Adding `return false` prevent the form or page from beeing submitted, and by that the AJAX call have a chance to finish, and the `window.location.href` redirect to go through.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler):

> Returning false from an event handler will automatically call
>   `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`.